# Installed new memory, dell laptop, bios posts (recognizes memory), windows won't load

Tags: windows-7, boot, laptop, memory, dell-latitude

I have a Dell Latitude e6520 that had 2X4GB memory. I found on sale 2X8GB crucial memory, which my IT buddy said the specs match and should work.  It has an intel i7-2620 processor with windows 7 x64.

I installed the new memory, bios posts, bios setup shows the 2 8 GB memory sticks, gets to the Windows icon, crashes, blue screen (but disappears too fast for me to read), restarts. I tried system repair, but no good.

So, just to get back my laptop back, I put the old memory back in, and now I am having the same error.  The system diagnostics run, all is good, including memory.  Bios posts, get to windows icon, after about 2 seconds, crash.

Running the memory check program now from a CD, at 77%, but all seems fine there, no errors so far.

Comment: Hopefully you grounded yourself and removed the battery when you swapped the RAM. It's possible you static shocked the board.

Comment: Yes to both, or at least, yes battery removed, and I grounded myself as I normally do when doing computer work. (though it was a humid day)  Would all diagnostics still check out (cpu, hardrive, video, memory) all said was working fine?

Comment: Yeah if they all check out then it's unlikely (it's unlikely anyway). I'd be interested in seeing if you can get that BSOD error code. Maybe you can take a video with a cell phone, play it back and pause so you can read it?

Comment: Try booting into Safe Mode. If you can do that, then try to change the setting for "Automatic Restart on System Failure". Right-click on My Computer and choose "Advanced System Settings", on the Advanced tab, under "Startup and Recovery", click "Settings". If "Automatic Restart" is checked, uncheck it and save changes. Now, when the PC BSODs, the screen should stay up and will help in troubleshooting the specific issue.

Comment: Can't get safe mode, f8 gives me "start normally" or "try to repair"